# program skipping a line of code

Tags: c++, textinput, skip

I have been working on this program for a while and I finally got rid of the compile errors. But when I tried it, the program basically skipped a line of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string nameOfFile = "";
  char index;
  char title[100];
  char name[100];
  char copyright[100];

  cout << "Welcome, and hello to the html templating software" << endl;
  cout << "Is this your index page?\ny/n" << endl;

  cin >> index;
  if (index=='n'){
    cout << "Enter the prefered name of this file" << endl;
    getline(cin, nameOfFile, '\n');
  }

  cout << "What will the title of the page be?" << endl;
  cin.getline(title, 100);

  cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
  cin.getline(name, 100);

  cout << "What is the copyright?" << endl;
  cin.getline(copyright, 100);

  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

You see how after asking if this is your index page it skips the next `cin.getline` function no matter the scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user entered the index, they also typed a newline, but your cin didn't remove it from the input stream.  So, your call to cin.getline returns immediately because of the leftover newline.

Add a call to [cin.ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) before the cin.getline to flush it out.

Answer (score 0):

replace getline(cin, nameOfFile, '\n')

with

cin >> nameOfFile

Comment: I can't do this I need to get spaces