# C++ code crashing, can't figure out why

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

my C++ code is crashing when I execute Search via Word (2) from my part of the code.

What it does is scan for a .txt file, then print out some information then it gives me options, my 2nd option is crashing my code.

The part of my code which is causing it to crash is, it's goal to to read user input then scan the file for a matching word then print out it's definition.

case 2:

```
{
                string searchWord;
                cout << "Enter a word to search for: ";
                std::getline(std::cin, searchWord);
                Word *myWord = Dic.findWord(searchWord);
                if (myWord != NULL)
                {
                    cout << myWord->definition;
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: Many potential problems can be avoided here by using a `std::vector`, which would also enable you to find words using a predicate.

Comment: @Moo-Juice how can i implement `std::vector`?

Answer (score 4):

Your logic in `findWords` is wrong, you should check for `MAX_WORDS` *before* you try to compare not afterwards. Like this

```
Word* Dictionary::findWord(string searchWord)
{
    int wordIndex = 0;
    while (wordIndex < MAX_WORDS) {
        if (myWords[wordIndex]->word.compare(searchWord) == 0) {
            return myWords[wordIndex];
        }
        wordIndex++;
    }
    cout << "word not in dictionary";
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hey cheers, that stopped the crashing, much appreciated. But now when I select two it just skips any user input and prints 

Enter a word to search for: word not in dictionary 
You have selected to exit

Comment: @user2775243 Well that's different question, very commonly asked here. Basically your input code is wrong. See here for a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241581/program-skipping-a-line-of-code/4241599#4241599, or do some searching yourself if that answer doesn't make sense, basically this question gets asked and answered all the time.